# Creating time series df with category and date and percentage change

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a dataframe like this:

```
category:      number:         date:
   dog           100         2020-01-01
   cat           50          2020-01-01
   dog           150         2020-01-02
   mouse         200         2020-01-01
   mouse         150         2020-01-02
   cat           100         2020-01-02
```

I am trying to create a dataframe that gets the percentage change for each individual category across each date, similar to this:

```
category:    number:        date:         percentage_change:
  dog          100        2020-01-01              -
  dog          150        2020-01-02             50%
  cat           50        2020-01-01              - 
  cat          100        2020-01-02             100%
  mouse        200        2020-01-01              -
  mouse        150        2020-01-02             25%
```

I have tried this:

```
df['number'].pct_change()
```

But this doesn't get pct_change for each category.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`GroupBy.pct_change`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.pct_change.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['category','date'])
df['percentage_change'] = df.groupby('category')['number'].pct_change()
print (df)
  category  number        date  percentage_change
1      cat      50  2020-01-01                NaN
5      cat     100  2020-01-02               1.00
0      dog     100  2020-01-01                NaN
2      dog     150  2020-01-02               0.50
3    mouse     200  2020-01-01                NaN
4    mouse     150  2020-01-02              -0.25
```

For percentages:

```
s = df['percentage_change'].mul(100).round().fillna(0,downcast='infer').astype(str) + '%'
df['percentage_change'] = np.where(df['percentage_change'].isna(), '-', s)
print (df)
  category  number        date percentage_change
1      cat      50  2020-01-01                 -
5      cat     100  2020-01-02              100%
0      dog     100  2020-01-01                 -
2      dog     150  2020-01-02               50%
3    mouse     200  2020-01-01                 -
4    mouse     150  2020-01-02              -25%
```

Comment: This is getting perc change when category changes (e.g. difference from last cat to first dog).

Comment: @bigmacattack - are you sure? it is group by `category`, so is  `difference from last cat to first dog`?

Comment: No I want to get the percentages for each respective category. For example mouse changes from 200 on 1st Jan 2020, to 150 on 2nd Jan 2020. This is a -25% decrease. I dont want the mouse perc change to take dog or cat into account, just the mouse value on the closest previous date.

Comment: @bigmacattack For me working like you need, for you not?